# How to Call AWS Lambda Service from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, aws-lambda, rdd, user-defined-functions

I would like to take each row of my Spark dataframe and process the data through a microservice that returns a new value (list) that I can then add as a new column. Since the dataframe will be processed concurrently, my thought was to structure this as a UDF that then calls a amazon lambda microservice which would scale dynamically.

Is this architecture feasible or been done before? If this is the recommended approach, how to do this?

Comment: Just an opinion - if both service and Spark applications are under your control you'll  double the cost of running your app and add significant latency. I wouldn't go this way unless I am forced by external requirements.

Comment: @user9613318 thanks for the feedback. But wouldnt I be saving a ton of processing time especially if the service duration was the bottleneck, since I would be running many rows concurrently through the service? This is not for an app. Rather its for a data processing pipeline for 50 million rows of data.

Comment: I am not sure if fully comprehend but I'd go with one or another - both can be scaled, and there is no reason to pay for one, when the other one is doing heavy lifting.